Best way to validate an incoming dataframe (via TSV) row by row
I'm loading a large data frame (15 columns x 30000 rows) from a tab-separated file using pandas.read_csv().  A sample data snippet shown in table below (Thank you to @Lukas for demonstrating how to get a show sample):



ID
Name
Latitude
List
Country




1
New York
40
a
United States (USA)


2
London
-97
c/d/e
United Kingdom (UK)


three
Rome
42
f/g
Italy (I)


4
Los Angeles
34N
f/g
USA



Would yield something like this after validation:



ID
Name
Latitude
List
Country
Code




1
New York
40
[a]
United States
USA


2
London
NaN
[c,d,e]
United Kingdom
UK


ROW REMOVED







4
Los Angeles
NaN
[f,g]
NaN
NaN



I would like to validate every row, and toss out rows that don't pass validation. For instance, I need to make sure that certain columns contain floats.  I originally thought of using the dtype parameter in read_csv() like thus:
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', dtype={"cola": str, "colb": float, ...})
However if read_csv encounters a non-float entry in the float column it will throw an exception and stop processing.
Types of checks I need to do on a per row basis:

Check that entry is of appropriate type, and convert string to said type
Check that values are within appropriate bounds (e.g. latitude is between -90 and 90)
For some entries I need to extract part of the data and put it in a new column
Convert some entries that are internally separated into lists that reside within the dataframe (e.g. "a/b/c" --> ["a", "b", "c"])

Depending on the error I may need to toss out the row, or simply NaN the bad value.  I do need to keep track of the failed validations and report them.
Currently I have implemented:
df.apply(lambda x: row_processor(x, error_log))
where row_processor() is the function that does all the checks returns an updated row (if appropriate) and an error_log entry.
Are there any flaws with that approach?  Other ideas I've had are just to brute force a 'for' loop across the rows, or to use df.apply() on one column at a time with a function specific to that column.
Is there data validation functionality with pandas that I'm missing?

read notice and provide [mre]. dont describe and show.

Why do you consider 30k rows large? This should be no problem to handle in memory, no need to handled it in a stream.

You could consider using the csv module to read and validate each row in the tsv rather than building a dataframe which you have to "repair" retrospectively. You can help yourself to get answers to your problem by showing the code you're currently using, sample input data and desired output data

Your sample input and output data do not align with the defined constraints/validations

Given that there is no example, here is what I would do. I do not consider 30k rows large, as this is something to be easily handled on any machine in memory.
Thus, I would load the data in memory and afterwards perform each check one after another. Since the checks all need to pass, it is fine to remove rows based on each check separately.
data = {
    'ID': ['1', '2', 'three', '4', '5'],
    'Latitude': ['45.0', '-100.0', '85.5', 'abc', '60.0'],
    'Name': ['John Doe', 'Jane Smith', 'Alice', 'Bob Johnson', 'Charlie Brown'],
    'Tags': ['a/b/c', 'd/e', 'f', 'g/h/i/j', 'k/l']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# perform checks:
# 1. convert types
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce')
df['Latitude'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Latitude'], errors='coerce')

# 2. check ranges
df = df[df['Latitude'].between(-90,90)].copy()

# 3. Remove NaN (i.e. non numeric IDs)
df = df[df['ID'].notnull()]

# 4. Split columns in multiple columns
def split_tags(tag_str):
    return tag_str.split('/') if isinstance(tag_str, str) else []
df['TagsList'] = df['Tags'].apply(split_tags)

# further checks ...

Hope that helps as guidance.

Thanks.  This is helpful.  I guess in terms of 30k rows being "large" it was not so much the memory, but the fact that when I get into the thousands, my gut tells me "avoid for loops across the rows".

yeah, its always best to utilize vectorized functions with pandas
